# Does Windows 10 Home Edition have IIS?

Tags: windows-10, iis

I know IIS has to be activated from Control Panel -> Turn Windows Features On or Off. I've done is in Windows 10 Pro version.

I want to buy a Windows 10 **Home** version and I want to be sure, that it is available there also in the Home version.

I will be just doing testing in the localhost. But according to my requirement I can't use IIS Express.

So, is IIS built in with Windows 10 **Home** version ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes it is possible to install IIS as an internal Windows feature.

Start **Run As** and enter *AppWiz.cpl*

You should see the Internet Information Services feature:

[image]